# Please Help - "/dev/sda1 is mounted." E2fsck: Cannot continue, aborting." Thanks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, mount

https://serving.photos.photobox.com/18156716f350a12bd31b61ca638825e809e811d642dc091097fdb48b9f5fac5062a5c74a.jpg

Here is the picture of my problem. I cannot boot my laptop and cannot log on to the Ubuntu screen. I have serious problems as I have copied the wrong info on the data recovery through Test disk.

What actually happened:

1. I used testdisk and backed up 2 files. 1 file was not important. Now the hard drive space is now completely full. I tried so many sources on Ask Ubuntu and Google, but it still doesn't help.
2. The monitor keeps showing a black screen with "_" a flashing underscore character `_`. The link that I uploaded is here.

Now my screen keeps blinking: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BN4twl0V8JQ

Comment: As I've already suggested, you must unmount the partition first, but it's easier to just boot a 'live' system (such as install media) and run `fsck` from there (as your live [dvd or thumb-drive] will be mounted & your disk partitions unmounted allowing fsck to proceed)

Comment: @guiverc How can I do this in a detailed step by step? I don't know how to unmount this. It is very confusing. I really appreaciate your time for your help.

Comment: If you don't know how to do it (you just execute the `umount` command, but the moment you do that you've lost access to the `fsck` command you want to execute next, so.... [*long & complicated*]), which is why I suggested booting a 'live' medium (such as Ubuntu install media), as it saves loads of command, plus is far less prone to error (thus safer for your data)

Comment: I also found out when I wrote on the command promt  "df -h" the /dev/sda1 is almost full which is very frustrating. Thank you again for your help

Comment: @guiverc I have excuted "umount" it still says "umount: bad usage"

Comment: You didn't tell it what to unmount - but if you do umount it; your commands are coming from that partition, so you'll lose access to commands (such as `fsck`, `mount` & more) which is why I suggested the live/install media (*so commands can come from that media, instead of your unmounted hdd*). I suggest again you use live media if your data is important to you, it's less risky.

Comment: @guiverc How do I do/use the live media?  or "booting live medium" I'm not very sure how to do this.

Comment: Insert your live media (eg. Ubuntu install cd/usb-thumb-drive), turn on your system & press whatever key pulls up the boot-select menu (on my current dell it's F12, on many hp's it's F9 - but laptops tend to be unique & model specific, i have one that uses an unlabeled black key, thinkpads usually use a blue key; some tell you on screen what to press though the message is brief). The key pulls up a menu asking you what to boot, you boot your cd/dvd/thumb-drive and then select 'try ubuntu'. You then use that gui to open terminal (ctrl+alt+T) & `fsck` , then navigate & delete the file...